# SQL Server connection string in Appsettings.json + .net Core 3.1

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core

I'm trying to setup and connect to my remote development SQL Server (SQL 2017) in appsettings.json within .NET Core 3.1, I have tried the following approaches yet without any success.

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
//"DefaultConnection1": "DATA SOURCE=[servername];UID=[username];PWD=[password];DATABASE=[databasename]",
//"DefaultConnection2": "Data Source=[servername]; Initial Catalog=[databasename];User ID=[username];Password=[password]",
//"DefaultConnection3": "DataSource=[servername];Initial Catalog=[databasename];User Id=[username];password=[password]",
"DefaultConnection4": "Server=[servername];Database=[databasename];User Id=[username];password=[password];Trusted_Connection=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;" 
},
```

**Error of DefaultConnection1:**

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'uid'.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(string
> keyword))

**Error of DefaultConnection2:**

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(string
> keyword)

**Error of DefaultConnection3:**

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(string
> keyword)

**Error of DefaultConnection4:**

> ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'server'.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(string
> keyword)

Any ideas, pointers or help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you use a placeholder like ([servername]) in the connection string, or just because of security reasons? I mean in your real appsettings, you explicitly have written the server IP or server name?

Comment: Hi Majid, these are just placeholder for security reasons, in the actual file, i used the correct credentials and able to log in via SSMS.

Comment: I wonder though if the error is occurring due to "Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for your help and advice, i might have just found the solution and am able to connection the SQL database successfully now, the problem was as following:

The following package was installed on the solution:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionStringBuilder
```

in Startup.cs the following line was used in the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlLite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

However after research i found out that i should rather use the following line:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Which was not accessible due the following package missing:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

After installing this package via package Manager using the following command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

I was able to access the SQL server using the following connection string:

```
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=[servername];Database=[databasename];Persist Security Info=True;User ID=[username];Password=[password];MultipleActiveResultSets=True;"
  },
```

For safety, as Christian pointed out, I removed also the other connectionstring references.

Comment: Since you are going to use a user name and a password you will need to add the next parameter to the connection string: "Integrated Security=True", this will make sure to use those parameters at the moment to make the connection, otherwise you will get an error.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it's just because you're not supposed to put comments (`//`) in JSON as JSON is a data format and doesn't support comments. So try actually removing the lines starting with `//` from your config.

Comment: Microsoft does have a json file format that does support comments. I'm not sure if that's a blessing or a curse, but they have it.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup in appsettings.json is fine.

Suppose the model in your cs file is mytestModel.
Here is the code to read the connection string:

```
public class mytestModel : PageModel
{
    public string connectstring = "";

    private IConfiguration MyConfiguration;
    public mytestModel (IConfiguration _configuration)
    {
        MyConfiguration = _configuration;
    }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        connectstring = this.MyConfiguration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection4");
    }   
}
```

It should be noted that the type of model (eg. PageModel) does not matter. The name of the model is what matters.